# mybatis - getting the mapped results of a sql string

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I use MyBatis extensively throughout my application, but in one specific instance I have a large user-generated SQL query (as a string) from an external control. The SQL it produces always has the same static fields returned, but the where clause is dynamic. I've discovered I can execute this query using *org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.SqlRunner*, but the result is always in the form of list of maps. I'd like to be able to use an existing resultMap specified in one of my many mapper XML files so that the query returns usable, mapped objects. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have any existing queries that you are currently using and also any that you have tried so we can try to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Map you query as usual but use [string substitution](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#String_Substitution) instead of parameter for where clause:

```
<select id="myQuery" resultMap="myResultMap">
  select field1, field2 from mytable
  where ${whereClause}
</select>
```

Note that instead of `#{}` syntax `${}` is used. It will insert specified parameter verbatim.